# How to Randomly pick from list in the class

Tags: python, random

I want to randomly pick a weapon and i want to write the name of it but the result is not like i expect what is wrong in that code?

```
import random
class Dusman:
    def __init__(self,name='',weapon='',armor=''):
        self.name= name
        self.weapon= weapon
        self.armor= armor

    def name(self):
        a=name
        a = input("Write a name: ")

    def weapon(self):
        weapon=["Sword","Axe","Topuz"]
        print(random.choice(weapon))


    def print(self):
        print("Name",self.name,"Weapon: ",self.weapon,"Armor: ",self.armor)

dusman1=Dusman()
dusman1.name
dusman1.weapon
dusman1.print()
```

Comment: Don't let things have the same name! They get overwritten.  Ask yourself: "is `Dusman.name` a function or a string?"

Comment: indentation needs to be fixed

Comment: also can you expound on 'the result is not like i expect', what are you getting and what do you expect

Comment: `random.choice(list_of_things)` is correct, but you've overwritten your variables with functions

Comment: You should really use an editor that supports linting, and use linting whenever you're writing code. A linter would've instantly caught the multitude of problems in your code regarding duplicate names. See here for more info: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Lint#Lint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your expected result?

```
import random

class Dusman:
    def __init__(self,name='',weapon='',armor=''):
        self._name= name
        self._weapon= weapon
        self._armor= armor

    def name(self):
        self._name = input("Write a name: ")

    def weapon(self):
        weapons=["Sword","Axe","Topuz"]
        self._weapon = random.choice(weapons)
        print(self._weapon)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {0} Weapon: {1} Armor: {2}".format(self._name,
                                                         self._weapon,
                                                         self._armor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dusman1=Dusman()
    dusman1.name()
    dusman1.weapon()
    print(dusman1)
```

Your problem is, that you have naming collisions. You are naming a variable the same as a function.

Comment: Thank a lot :) but i tried it with out if _name_ it worked as the same. What does if _name_ function actually do?

Comment: You could try to use a IDE like PyCharm. It will help you a lot with this kind of problems.

Comment: I use pycharm helps a lot but i focused on wrong thing so i couldn't find my mistake but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you only print the choice.

You need to set the result of the choice to the `weapon` instance variable:

```
def weapon(self):
    weapons = ["Sword", "Axe", "Topuz"]
    self.weapon = random.choice(weapons)
```